# Celery use local settings instead of RabbitMQ settings for an unknown reason

Tags: python, django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I work with Django 1.9, Celery 3.1.23, Redis 2.10.5 - The site is on Heroku. RabbitMQ is used as message broker (CloudAMQP).

My settings.py is as follow:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://xxx:yyyyyy@salamander.rmq.cloudamqp.com/xxx'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 100
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = ['json']
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
if BROKER_URL == "django://":
    INSTALLED_APPS += ("kombu.transport.django",)
```

And I always get the following error message:

```
Mar 16 14:59:38 terradiem app/worker.1:  [2017-03-16 14:59:37,844: ERROR/Beat] beat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 32.0 seconds... 
Mar 16 14:59:38 terradiem app/worker.1:  [2017-03-16 14:59:37,847: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

It seems that local settings (amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//) override the cloudamqp but I can't identify why.

Here is the log:

```
Mar 16 15:11:31 myapp heroku/worker.1:  Process exited with status 0 
Mar 16 15:11:46 myapp heroku/worker.1:  Starting process with command `python manage.py celery worker --beat --loglevel=info` 
Mar 16 15:11:46 myapp  heroku/worker.1:  State changed from starting to up 
Mar 16 15:11:47 myapp heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `gunicorn terradiem.wsgi --log-file -` 
Mar 16 15:11:49 myapp app/web.1:  [2017-03-16 14:11:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/web.1:  [2017-03-16 14:11:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:16874 (4) 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/web.1:  [2017-03-16 14:11:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp  app/web.1:  [2017-03-16 14:11:49 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:   -------------- celery@XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXv3.1.23 (Cipater) 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  ---- **** -----  
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-112-generic-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  -- * - **** ---  
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  - ** ---------- [config] 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  - ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7f15b9bd27d0 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672// 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled:// 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork) 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  -- ******* ----  
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  --- ***** ----- [queues] 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:   -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery 
Mar 16 15:11:50 myapp app/worker.1:  [tasks] 
Mar 16 15:11:50 terradiem app/worker.1:    . fileupload.views.create_thumbnail
```

Do you have any idea why Django would not use my settings?

Comment: What are the local settings? How are they being imported?

Comment: Thanks for the answyer. I don't have a local settings file. My local settings are defined in settings.py when necessary, with "if ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD': ... ".  Do you have any particular setting in mind ?